# Are there any options to control organization for the new photo app?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos

Whichever way we set 'Summarize Photos', my wife's iphone shows the same unwieldy display of the thousands of pictures she has synced from iPhoto to her iPhone. Organized by date with tiny thumbnails. No sign of her events or albums.

Is there any way to make 'Photos' respect an organization from iPhoto?

Answer (score 1):

There are three types of organizations in iPhone now in iOS 7.

According to Years, months and dates and it is not a replication of iPhoto as well.

and when you can make an album of what ever pic's you wanted, you can see them in albums tab.

Comment: Nothing from iphoto's albums shows up in the Albums tab.

Comment: Thats means you've not check marked those albums in your itunes after connecting the device.

Comment: I checked 'all albums'.